# Creating PostgreSQL application in Openshift from shell

Tags: openshift

I'd need to create a PostgreSQL application in Openshift 4 using the 'oc' commandline.
I can see that by adding the app from the Catalog, the application is correctly added.
On the other hand, by using the following shell, the Pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff:

```
oc new-app -e POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres -e POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=demodb postgresql
```

The following error is contained in the log file.

```
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": Operation not permitted
```

Which is the correct shell to start up PostgreSQL?
Thanks

Comment: 1) Which container are you using? you are only specifying `postgresql` in your question. 2) What is the output from `oc logs <pod>`?

Comment: You should use the postgresql-ephemeral or postgresql-persistent templates, rather than try and deploy the image itself. The templates setup extra stuff for you. You can still use the templates from the command line. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/using_images/db_images/postgresql.html#creating-a-database-service-from-a-template